# string format for intptr_t and uintptr_t

Tags: c, formatting, printf, scanf

What is the string format for `intptr_t` and  `uintptr_t`  which is valid for both the 32 and 64 bit architecture .

EDIT

```
warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type "AAA"
```

This is the warning i am getting  in 64 bit but not in 32 bit.

```
  intptr_t  AAA
```

Answer (score 74):

That would be the following macros from `inttypes.h`:

For `printf`:
`PRIdPTR PRIiPTR PRIoPTR PRIuPTR PRIxPTR PRIXPTR`

For `scanf`:
`SCNdPTR SCNiPTR SCNoPTR SCNuPTR SCNxPTR`

Usage example:

```
uintptr_t p = SOME_VALUE;
printf("Here's a pointer for you: %" PRIxPTR "\n", p);
```

Comment: Usage example: `uinptr_t p = SOME_VALUE; printf("Here's a pointer for you: %" PRIxPTR "\n", p);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,my question may not be so precise... what exactly i intend to know if there any strong format like **"%d"** for integer and so on. I am getting some warning depending upon the hardware architecture.I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider using the 'z' modifier. This will convert anything that corresponds to a size_t og ssize_t, and I have found that it works with (u)intptr_t as well.

For example:

intptr_t   ip = ...;
printf("ip = %zd\n", ip);

Comment: Congratulations, you have found undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Would `void *p = ...; printf("%td", (ptrdiff_t)p);` be (the same kind of) UB?

Answer (score 0):

`%p` should work as a replacement for `%x`, since `uintptr_t` is defined to be an unsigned integer with the same size as a pointer on the platform.

EDIT: Unfortunately, at least on my compiler you have to cast the variable to (void *). However, I think it is safe to cast uintptr_t to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
####################################### CPP type proving code (identifying type by typeid)
$ cat typeid.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <typeinfo>

#define name(t) printf("%30s : %s\n", #t, typeid(t).name())

// g++|clang++ -o ./typeid.exe typeid.cpp -m32 && ./typeid.exe
// g++|clang++ -o ./typeid.exe typeid.cpp -m64 && ./typeid.exe
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    name(ptrdiff_t);
    name(intptr_t);
    name(uintptr_t);

    return 0;
}

####################################### C type proving code (identifying type by _Generic)
$ cat typeid.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>

/* matches the type name of an expression */
#define name_match(e) _Generic((e), \
                 _Bool: "_Bool", \
                  char: "char", \
           signed char: "signed char", \
         unsigned char: "unsigned char", \
                 short: "short", \
        unsigned short: "unsigned short", \
                   int: "int", \
          unsigned int: "unsigned int", \
                  long: "long", \
         unsigned long: "unsigned long", \
             long long: "long long", \
    unsigned long long: "unsigned long long", \
                 float: "float", \
                double: "double", \
           long double: "long double", \
               default: "unknown")

#define name(t, e) printf("%30s : %s\n", #t, name_match(e))

int main() {
    ptrdiff_t ptrdiff_v = 0;
    intptr_t  intptr_v = 0;
    uintptr_t uintptr_v = 0;

    name(ptrdiff_t, ptrdiff_v);
    name(intptr_t,  intptr_v);
    name(uintptr_t, uintptr_v);
}

####################################### run in arch32
$ clang++ -o ./typeid.exe typeid.cpp -m32 && ./typeid.exe
                     ptrdiff_t : i
                      intptr_t : i
                     uintptr_t : j

$ clang -o ./typeid.exe typeid.c -m32 && ./typeid.exe      
                     ptrdiff_t : int
                      intptr_t : int
                     uintptr_t : unsigned int
result:
     intptr_t == ptrdiff_t
    uintptr_t == unsigned ptrdiff_t

####################################### run in arch64
$ clang++ -o ./typeid.exe typeid.cpp -m64 && ./typeid.exe
                     ptrdiff_t : l
                      intptr_t : l
                     uintptr_t : m

$ clang -o ./typeid.exe typeid.c -m64 && ./typeid.exe   
                     ptrdiff_t : long
                      intptr_t : long
                     uintptr_t : unsigned long
result:
     intptr_t == ptrdiff_t
    uintptr_t == unsigned ptrdiff_t

####################################### man 3 printf
t -- A following integer conversion corresponds to a ptrdiff_t argument.

####################################### conclusion
//  intptr_t == ptrdiff_t
// uintptr_t == unsigned ptrdiff_t
// so:
//     1)  intptr_t has string format %td
//     2) uintptr_t has string format %tu

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    intptr_t  x = 0;
    uintptr_t y = 0;

    scanf("%td %tu", &x, &y);
    printf("out: %td %tu\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry but this question is tagged with C so why answer with a cpp solution ?

Comment: using '#include <typeinfo>' need cpp suffix. As far as I know, printf is C function, not CPP funtion, std::printf is CPP funtion.

Comment: @Stargateur  You said this is a cpp solution, just because there is a cpp suffix?

Comment: `typeid` don't exist in C, sooooooo.

Comment: Added a __Generic version for C.

Answer (score -1):

I'm compiling some code in an environment which for some reason does *not* have the `PRI.PTR` macros defined in `inttypes.h`, and in which `intptr_t` is defined as `int` in 32 bit and `long int` in 64 bit.

I hacked around the warnings by using a `%li` format specifier and casting the variables to `long int` in the `printf` parameters. This is safe *within this environment* because an `intptr_t` can never be longer than a `long int`, as described above.

I wouldn't recommend using this solution if you can avoid it, but it's solved the warnings, at least.

Comment: if you anyways have to use a cast, then use %jd (%ju, %jx, %jo) and cast to intmax_t (/uintmax_t)

Comment: @WilliamCushing That’s a better idea. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think even `long int` is unsafe, and you should try `long long int`, which must exist because you are working on a 64-bit architecture and you have `intptr_t` already.

On some 64-bit architectures (I think Microsoft Windows would be so), `long int` may be kept in 32-bit width, to satisfy the MS-DOS-age assumption that `short int` is always 16-bit and `long int` is always 32-bit.

Even on those platforms with 32-bit `long int`, `printf("%llx", (unsigned long long)AAA);` would work. And you should consider more preferrable form `printf("%jx", (uintmax_t)AAA);` if possible.

Note that for some old compilers you might need to use `"%Lx"` (for GNU C, with casting to `unsigned long long`) or `"%I64x"` (for Visual C++, with casting to `__uint64`) for 64-bit integers.

P. S.
`%p` may not be good in this case, because `%p` may print the bareword `0x` before the hexadecimals and/or may print a zero-padded value. If the both is applied, for example, the code `printf("%p\n", (void*)16);` will print `0x00000010` on 32-bit platforms and `0x0000000000000010` on 64-bit platforms; the poster should have hoped just `10` be printed.