# POSIX C Threads - Passing integer to thread func

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, posix, void-pointers

I have a segmentation fault error in my program. I am practising with multithreading programs in POSIX C. I run these programs in FREEBSD system.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 15

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
        printf("Hello World from thread: %p \n", threadid);
        fflush(NULL);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int rtrn, *i;
        pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

        for((*i)=0; (*i)<NUM_THREADS; (*i)++)
        {
                if( pthread_create(&threads[(*i)], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)i) != 0)
                {
                        printf("Error code %d detected while thread %d was being created.", rtrn, *i);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I had to turn i integer variable into pointer integer because this solved a error during compiling (line 22: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size)

The compile error has been resolved but now when I run the program, it shows me this: Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped)

Probably the previous warning has not been resolved but I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: You never initialize `i` to a sensible value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is pass an *id* to the calling thread you can do so by burying it *in* the `void*` parameter, and do so portably. Using the integer types like `intptr_t`, which is "the integer large enough to hold a data pointer" on your platform, I'm fairly sure this is closer to what you want.

Also, POSIX requires stdio functions on `FILE*` to be thread-safe, so you can lose the `fflush()` (which wasn't really helping anyway), though if you're going to search for why this is, it isn't obvious. Look in the documentation for [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html), and note the mention that all stdio functions that operate on `FILE*` (of which `printf()` does on `stdout`) should behave as if they invoke `flockfile`and `funlockfile` to acquire access to the stream.) There is no specification on the *atomicity* of the locking (it could be down to the character for all you know, in which case interleaving runs amok) but it should still be none-the-less safe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 15

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
    intptr_t id = (intptr_t)threadid;
    printf("Hello World from thread: %" PRIiPTR "\n", id);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    intptr_t i=0;
    int res;

    for(i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        if( (res = pthread_create(threads+i, NULL, PrintHello, (void *)i)) != 0)
            printf("Error code %d detected while thread %" PRIiPTR " was being created.", res, i);
    }

    // wait for all to complete
    for (i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello World from thread: 0
Hello World from thread: 1
Hello World from thread: 2
Hello World from thread: 3
Hello World from thread: 4
Hello World from thread: 5
Hello World from thread: 6
Hello World from thread: 7
Hello World from thread: 8
Hello World from thread: 9
Hello World from thread: 10
Hello World from thread: 11
Hello World from thread: 12
Hello World from thread: 14
Hello World from thread: 13
```

Finally, if you're doing a double-take on the odd looking `PRIiPTR` buried in the format strings it should be worth your time to read [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795978/string-format-for-intptr-t-and-uintptr-t). It is the portable mechanism for using the right "%" type to dump `intptr_t` as formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for the variable `i`. Right now it's a pointer pointing somewhere, but you definitely do not owe that piece of memory.

After a

```
i = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
```

You will have a valid piece of memory, initialized to 0 (thanks to `calloc`).

On the other end, if you will use `i` via a pointer you might have a funny behaviour depending how your OS is starting the threads. All threads will use the same address, so some of them might get the same value printed on the screen :) If you want to print out 10 different numbers via thread go with `0x90`'s answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes:

1. Removed unnecessary header files.
2. Declared a global array for the id. Better to share a global array or on heap than on stack.
3. Used the array instead a pointer.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 15

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
    printf("Hello World from thread: %d \n", *(int *)threadid);
    fflush(NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

static int id[NUM_THREADS];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rtrn;
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    for(int i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++) {
         id[i] = i; 
         if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)&id[i]))
             printf("Error code %d detected while thread %d was being created.", rtrn, i);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Will output:

```
Hello World from thread: 0 
Hello World from thread: 1 
Hello World from thread: 2 
Hello World from thread: 3 
Hello World from thread: 4 
Hello World from thread: 5 
Hello World from thread: 6 
Hello World from thread: 7 
Hello World from thread: 8 
Hello World from thread: 9 
Hello World from thread: 10 
Hello World from thread: 11 
Hello World from thread: 12 
Hello World from thread: 13 
Hello World from thread: 14
```