# If `malloc(0)` returns a non-null pointer, can I pass that to `free`?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I've been reading over discussions of how `malloc` behaves when you request a zero sized block.

I understand that the behavior of `malloc(0)` is implementation-defined, and it is supposed to either return a null pointer, *or* a non-null pointer that I am nonetheless not supposed to access. (Which makes sense, since there's no guarantee that it points to any usable memory.)

However, if a get such a nonaccessable non-null pointer, am I allowed to pass it to `free` in the usual way? Or is that illegal, since the pointer I get from `malloc(0)` may not point to an actual allocated block of memory?

Concretely, does the following code have well-defined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int* x = (int*) malloc(0);
    if (x == NULL) {
        printf("Got NULL\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Got nonnull %p\n", x);
    }
    free(x); // is calling `free` here okay?
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can `free` the result of `malloc`

Comment: Wrong format specifier in printf though, cast to unsigned long if you want to use `lx`

Comment: "If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().", https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc, RTFM :p.

Comment: yeah I'm on OS X and their man pages often aren't as good as those on Linux.

Comment: You are also guaranteed to be able to pass `NULL` to `free()`. Whatever `malloc()` returns can be safely `free()`d (once).

Comment: @M.M, no don't cast pointers, at all. In code like this use `void*` instead of `int*`, don't cast the result of `malloc` anyhow, and use the `%p` specifier to print pointers.

Comment: @JensGustedt `%p` format is not defined whether it's hex, decimal, what the formatting is... there are reasons to convert pointers to integers for printing, to control the output format

Comment: @M.M, and there are good reasons that this is implementation defined, pointers are not always expressible as simple numbers. Those platforms where they are and that I know of, they use hex representation. Do you know of any other?

Comment: The bigger problem is that casting a pointer to `unsigned long` will truncate it on LLP64 platforms like MSVC++.  If you have to cast a pointer to an integer, cast it to `uintptr_t`.

Comment: [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714), and [use `%p` to print pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/995714). @M.M if you want to control the format, at least cast to [`uintptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/995714) and print with [`PRI?PTR`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5795978/995714)

Comment: somewhat ironically, my original version of the question did cast to ... well, to `intptr_t` (not `uintptr_t`), but my heart was in the right place...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The C99 standard (actually WG14/N1124. Committee Draft -- May 6, 2005. ISO/IEC 9899:TC2) says about `malloc()`:

> The pointer returned points to the start (lowest byte
>   address) of the allocated space. If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is
>   returned. If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation defined:
>   either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some
>   nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object

and about `free()`:

> Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.

IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (POSIX), 2016 Edition says about `free()`:

> The free() function shall cause the space pointed to by ptr to be
>   deallocated; that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is
>   a null pointer, no action shall occur. Otherwise, if the argument does
>   not match a pointer earlier returned by a function in POSIX.1-2008
>   that allocates memory as if by malloc(), or if the space has been
>   deallocated by a call to free() or realloc(), the behavior is
>   undefined.

So, whatever `*alloc()` returns, you can pass to `free()`.

**As for the current implementations of `malloc()`:**

FreeBSD uses the contributed jemalloc which does

```
void *
je_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ret;
    size_t usize JEMALLOC_CC_SILENCE_INIT(0);

    if (size == 0)
        size = 1;
    [...]
```

Whereas Apple's libmalloc does

```
void *
szone_memalign(szone_t *szone, size_t alignment, size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0) {
        size = 1; // Ensures we'll return an aligned free()-able pointer
    [...]
```

The GLIBC also changes the requested size; it is using a call to this macro with the requested size in bytes as the parameter to align the size to a certain boundary or simply the minimum allocation size:

```
#define request2size(req)                                       \
    (((req) + SIZE_SZ + MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK < MINSIZE)  ?         \
    MINSIZE :                                                   \
    ((req) + SIZE_SZ + MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK) & ~MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK)
```

Answer (score 24):

Yes, in fact you must do so to avoid a probable memory leak.

The malloc system typically returns a hidden control block in the space immediately before the pointer, with information such as allocation size. If allocation size is zero, this block still exists and occupies memory, if malloc returns non-null.

Comment: I see. (I had assumed it might use a sentinel block for zero-sized allocations, but I can believe that is not a universal choice. Looking at the Linux man page, the use of the phrase "or a unique pointer value" leads me to wonder if using a sentinel would even be legal...)

Comment: If malloc returns NULL, then you cannot pass that to free as you got no memory so neither is there a hidden control block. However, free accepts a null pointer and just ignores it.

Comment: The problem is you you get code like if(!allocatedptr) outofmemoryhandler() which fires if N = 0 and malloc returns NULL. It's arguably better to return a value. I just tested it and on the system installed on this computer (clang) I get a non-zero return.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie your comment is a bit confusing; if malloc returns NULL then you CAN pass it to free

Comment: @M.M., yes you can, as I say, because it just ignores this "error" (that is, I find it an error to call free with NULL-pointer).

Comment: @M.M., NULL is a _non_-result (a result indicating an error or out-of-memory).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie-- which is why the Standard specifies ["If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Like Malcolm's comment says, in practice most people assume `malloc` returning null means OOM. According to the language, this is not a correct assumption, as there is a scenario where `malloc` is permitted to return null while still having memory available. So no, it's not indicating OOM. You and many others are free to assume that, of course, but don't go around saying it's definitely so. It *would* be correct to say that `malloc` returning null on a non-zero size would indicate OOM - yes, that's a technically but welcome to language lawyer land.

Comment: @GManNickG It's quite abnormal to call `malloc(0)` in the first place. So while you're technically true, in practice when `malloc()` returns `NULL` it's because of OOM.