# Preforming manipulations on C memory addresses as char* to output.

Tags: c

I'm attempting to print the address of all arguments in argv as segmented chars.

The address of argv[0]

```
0x7ffdf0451078
```

I want to print this as

```
0x7ffd f0 45 10 78
```

Then truncate the beginning id, and print this into a formatted gird similar to

```
 +------+------+------+------+
 |  f0  |  45  |  10  |  78  | 
 +------+------+------+------+
```

I'm assuming the easiest way to accomplish this is to hold the address of argv[0] as a string, or char array, and then do some manipulation to that string / array.

However I have not been able to get the address into any type of container thus far.

Comment: see [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/)/[sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). You can pass a pointer with `%p` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
char str[100];
sprintf(str, "%p", argv[0]);
```

Now `str` would have `"0x7ffdf0451078"` if `argv[0]` is `0x7ffdf0451078`.

You need only the `f0451078` part. ie, the `str+6` part.

Now use `sscanf()` like

```
char d[4][3];
sscanf(str+6, "%2s%2s%2s%2s", d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3]);
```

and print them as you need.

If you used the `%x` format specifier instead of `%p`, use `str+4`.

Demo [here](https://ideone.com/3dxgCS).

Comment: Ahh yes, this looks to work correctly.

for the 

`sscanf(str+4, "%2s%2s%2s%2s", d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3]);`

it should be a +6, otherwise it grabs the incorrect section of the address.

Answer (score 1):

```
void *ptr = argv[0];
printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n",
       (int)((ptr / 0x1000000) & 0xff),
       (int)((ptr / 0x10000) & 0xff),
       (int)((ptr / 0x100) & 0xff),
       (int)(ptr & 0xff));
```

Comment: I see what you're doing in this segment, however it is giving me an error for each segmentation

`error: invalid operands of types ‘void*’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator/’
        (int)((ptr / 0x100) & 0xff),`

Answer (score 1):

If you want control over the representation of the pointer, you may wish to convert it to `intptr_t` so you have confidence in the behavior of `printf` style specifiers. (The output format of `%p` is implementation-defined.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    intptr_t address = (intptr_t) &argv[0];

    char repr[1 + 2*sizeof(intptr_t)]; // 2 chars per byte plus a '\0'
    snprintf(repr, sizeof repr, "%" PRIxPTR, address); // this is the magic

    printf("0x%.4s %.2s %.2s %.2s %.2s\n", repr, repr+4, repr+6, repr+8, repr+10);
    // output: 0x7ffd f0 45 10 78

    printf("+------+------+------+------+\n");
    printf("|  %.2s  |  %.2s  |  %.2s  |  %.2s  |\n", repr+4, repr+6, repr+8, repr+10);
    printf("+------+------+------+------+\n");
    // output:
    // +------+------+------+------+
    // |  f0  |  45  |  10  |  78  | 
    // +------+------+------+------+
}
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795978/string-format-for-intptr-t-and-uintptr-t) for formatting an `intptr_t`, and I used the precision field of the `%s` format specifier to print sections of the string that `snprintf` created.

Although `repr`'s size is defined in terms of `sizeof(intptr_t)`, the printing code here assumes a 24 bit address.