# how to printf 0x0000000 instead of (nil) and 0x08ffffff instead of 0x8ffffff in c

Tags: c, pointers, printf, stdout

I am trying to use the `stdout stream` to print `0x00000000` instead of `(nil)` and `0x08ffffff` instead of `0x8ffffff`.

So basically, `char *ptr1 = 0x00000000` and `char *ptr2 = 0x08ffffff`.

When I run

```
printf("start of address is %p and end of address is %p", ptr1, ptr2);
```

I get

```
start of address is (nil) and end of address is 0x8ffffff
```

I actually found a way around this and I would actually do this:

```
char *ptr1 = 0x00000000; 
char *ptr2 = 0x08ffffff;
printf("start 0x%08x and end 0x%08x\n",ptr1, ptr2);
```

This generates

```
start 0x00000000 and end 0x08ffffff
```

However, the compiler sends the following warning:

```
warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, 
but argument 3 has type ‘void *’ [-Wformat=]
```

How should I modify printf to adjust the output print?

Comment: Cast it to `uintptr_t` and print as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795978/string-format-for-intptr-t-and-uintptr-t

Comment: `printf("start %08x and end %08x\n", (uint32_t)ptr1, (uint32_t)ptr2);`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Very bad idea, as 64-bit environments are increasingly common.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I get this error 

```error: ‘uint32_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             printf("%08x - %08x RW\n",(uint32_t)regions[i].from,(uint32_t)regions[i].to);```

Comment: @Hadi If there's a chance you'll compile this code in a 64-bit environment, you won't want to use `uint32_t` like this anyway.

Comment: `#include <stdint.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to have any control over how addresses are printed, you must convert them to an integer type. The specifications for printing pointers with `%p` are inadequate. To do this, you can include `<stdint.h>` and use the type `uintptr_t`, which is an unsigned integer type suitable for some work with addresses.

Second, the header `<inttypes.h>` provides a macro `PRIxPTR` that provides a `printf` conversion specifier for printing `uintptr_t` values in hexadecimal.

Third, you can add a flag `0` and a minimum field width `8` to request the conversion pad with zeros to at least eight digits.

Here is sample code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static void PrintAddress(const void *p)
{
    uintptr_t u = (uintptr_t) p;
    printf("0x%08" PRIxPTR, u);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr1 = (char *) 0x00000000;
    char *ptr2 = (char *) 0x08ffffff;
    printf("Start of address is ");
    PrintAddress(ptr1);
    printf(" and end of address is ");
    PrintAddress(ptr2);
    printf(".\n");
}
```

Better yet, you can adapt the field width to the size of `uintptr_t` in your C implementation by including `<limits.h>` and calculating the number of digits needed:

```
    printf("0x%0*" PRIxPTR, ((int) sizeof u * CHAR_BIT + 3) / 4, u);
```

Note that directly setting pointers to hard-coded constant values, as you do with the initializations of `ptr1` and `ptr2`, is rare. It is generally used in doing special things with hardware. When you are deliberately converting an integer to a pointer, you should use a cast to avoid a compiler warning.

Comment: how about `(sizeof u * CHAR_BIT + 3) / 4` so that it works on my 9-bit char / 18-bit address computer :-P

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Okay.

Comment: note that it's possible a conforming system won't support `uintptr_t` . In which case we can loop through the bytes of the number (obtained via whichever method desired) printing two nibbles at a time

Comment: @M.M: Well, I would write code for that, but to support it and the non-8 `CHAR_BIT` implementation, we would have to write code that handles hexadecimal digits split across the implementation’s “bytes,” i.e., maintain a bit-shift buffer. Or otherwise accommodate the odd-size bytes. I think I will not go that far right now.